Github login by every difference path
I am using Window 11, and use Tortoisegit,and try to use  multi github account in my Window for multi path of github.
Git clone will require username/passwordToken by every difference path.

I cost some hours to research this solution, write for me to use later, and anyone need it.
git config --global credential.helper manager-core
git config --global credential.useHttpPath true

FYI: "passwordToken" can take from Settings/Developer Settings/Tokens(classic)
